# Do an Application's multiple palettes automatically get grouped together?

Tags: front-end, palettes

Among dozens of Applications folders in my `$UserBaseDirectory`, many have associated palettes in their own FrontEnd/Palettes subfolders.

A couple have multiple palettes, grouped in their folder tree as follows:

> $UserBaseDirectory/Applications/TheAppName/FrontEnd/Palettes/TheAppName/palette1
>
> $UserBaseDirectory/Applications/TheAppName/FrontEnd/Palettes/TheAppName/palette2

Then in the drop-down Palettes menu I see, before all other app's single menu entries, an entry, `TheAppName`;  when I click that item, I get a fly-out menu with the names of the individual palettes `Palette1`, `Palette2`. (Sorry, I cannot seem to catch this in a screenshot.)

**Does this happen automatically**, or is there some option in those palettes that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those palettes are gathered under a common item 'TheAppName' because this is the structure FE finds in your `Applications/TheAppName/FrontEnd/Palettes/...`

Was it `Palettes/palette2` and you would see a flat list next to other items in the menu.

There is one related option though: `MenuSortingValue`. If affects the order of e.g. palettes in the menu or their presence at all.